# In App settings tableview from Settings bundle

Tags: ios, xcode5, tableview, appsettings, settings.bundle

I want to create a **TableView** which is automatically **generated** from the **Settings.bundle**. There used to be a framework **InAppSettings** but this *isn't working with iOS 7 and up*. Is there any other code/tutorial for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been searching around and couldn't find a boilerplate solution so created my own code for doing this. It supports the setting types **Title**, **Group**, **Text Field**,  **Multi Value** and **Toggle Switch**.

It does *NOT SUPPORT* **Slider**.

This solution does support portrait AND landscape mode and can also handle changing over device orientations.

I have published the code and readme on my GIT.

https://github.com/KingIsulgard/iOS-InApp-Settings-TableView/blob/master/README.md